# Why the Str::ulid() method in Laravel always return the ulid in uppercase?

Tags: php, laravel, ulid

I am using Laravel and when I get the result of this method:

```
return (string) Str::ulid();
```

it returns this:

> 01H32R5Z0NDY1WRYWKWT20ZQYM

I was trying the get something like this:

> 01gd6r360bp37zj17nxb55yv40

I would like it to return a mix of uppercase and lowercase characters, not only uppercase, this is weird because in the laravel documentacion it shows a mix of uppercase and lowercase characteres

Comment: [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-str-ulid) shows it all lower case. Internally it seems to use [symfony/uid](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/uid.html#ulids) so maybe try `Str::ulid()->toBase58()`

Comment: The example from the documentation can be achived by just passing the result to `strtolower`.

Answer (score 0):

ULID doesn't support mix case. You can use a function which can transform any case to mix case:

```
function toMixCase(string $string): string
{
    $result = strtolower($string);
    $length = strlen($result);
    $numberOrUpperSymbols = random_int(0, $length - 1);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOrUpperSymbols; $i++) {
        $randomIndex = random_int(0, $length - 1);
        $result[$randomIndex] = strtoupper($result[$randomIndex]);
    }

    return $result;
}

$ulid = toMixCase(Str::ulid()->toString());
```

Or you just can use `Str::random(26)`. It's not the ULID but in this case you will get a random string with mix case by default